# How to improve this awk code to reduce processing time

Tags: awk

I have 400 tab-delimited text files with 6 million rows in each file. Below is the format of the files:

```
 ### input.txt 
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ID1     str1    234     cond1   0
ID1     str2    567     cond1   0
ID1     str3    789     cond1   1
ID1     str4    123     cond1   1

### file1.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ID2     str1    235     cond1   0
ID2     str2    567     cond2   3
ID2     str3    789     cond1   3
ID2     str4    123     cond2   0

### file2.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
ID3     str1    235     cond1   0
ID3     str2    567     cond2   4
ID3     str3    789     cond1   1
```

I am trying to add values in $1 from the rest of the file1..filen to $6 in input.txt file by using:

```
conditions:
1. columns $2 and $3 as key 
2. If the key is found in files1...filen then if $5>=2 add the value from  $1 to $6 in the input file.
```

Code:

```
awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '!c {
    c=$0"\tcol6";
    next
}
NR==FNR {
    a[$2$3]=$0 "\t";
    next
}
{
    if ($5>=2) {
        a[$2$3]=a[$2$3] $1 ","
    }
}
END {
     print c;
     for (i in a) {
        print a[i]
    }
}' input.txt file1..filen.txt
```

The output from the above code is as expected:

```
Output.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
ID1    str2    567    cond1    0    ID2,ID3,
ID1    str4    123    cond1    1    
ID1    str1    234    cond1    0    
ID1    str3    789    cond1    1    ID2,
```

However, the problem is that the code is very slow as it has to iterate each key in input.txt through 400 files with 6 million rows in each file. This takes several hours to few days.  Could someone suggest a better way to reduce the processing time in awk or using other scripts.

Any help would really save lot of time.

Comment: it would be better to expand the explanation of your code.

Comment: It is `400*6mi= 2.4 billion rows`.  Several hours sounds normal...

Comment: Just a side comment -- about 12 years ago, awk was my tool of choice. It was small and light and simple, compared to Perl's big bloated glob of crud. Then I got stuck on a task, and had a hellish time debugging. I finally gave up, and a few years after that I turned to Python, which is reasonably fast and has debug support in several IDEs (PyDev, PyCharm, etc.). If you really want fast, you'll probably need to use a language that is compilable down to machine code (C), or has a fast JIT (Java) or has libraries compiled to machine code that can abstract a large enough chunk to speed up.

Comment: Create an index and update it so you don't need to reprocess everything every time?

Comment: Two ideas: You might have a look at [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) which might speed up things as it is a very fast AWK implementation on a bytecode interpreter.
Second idea: You might consider sorting the corresponding files by columns 2 and 3 and write the result to a new file. After that, you could work with this sorted file and adapt your code. After sorting you can be sure that -- whenever the content of column 2 changes -- this value does not occur again in the sorted file.

Comment: Is this step really needed : `b[$2$3]=b[$2$3] ? b[$2$3]","$1 : $1`  ? If you find a match, probably you can print out the data right there and avoid storing it?

Comment: You can do the filtering `$5>=2` upfront in parallel which will reduce the processing time if the files are sparse in that condition.

Comment: @ThomasG Could you show what you mean it in the command?

Comment: @EtanReisner Could you let me know how to create the index to update?

Comment: @karakfa I do not understand "upfront in parallel" Do you mean perform $5>3 on the files before using the awk command?

Comment: Exactly, since there is no contention you can run them in parallel as many as your resources allow.

Comment: I meant storing only `a` from input.txt and avoid storing `b` from all other files. I will post the code shortly.

Comment: @EtanReisner Could you help to implement what you mean.

Comment: Not currently. I don't have the time to fully understand the problem space or the code you currently have. That said if you don't have a meaningful "update" step which is different then "reprocess everything" then it won't help. When do you need to redo this work? How does new data get added?

Comment: I have updated the used code and conditions to add new data to the input file. The code gives the output as expected. But it takes several hours to process through hundred of files. It would be helpful to hear from you if there is turnaround to reduce the processing time by updating instead of reprocessing.

Comment: @Kent : `2.4 billion rows` is at most a few minutes in `awk`. If it's 20+ minutes, there's probably some major bottleneck inherent to the algorithm chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input.txt
Sam    string    POS    Zyg    QUAL
WSS    1    125    hom    4973.77
WSS    1    810    hom    3548.77
WSS    1    389    hom    62.74
WSS    1    689    hom    4.12


file1.txt
 Sam   string    POS    Zyg    QUAL
 AC0    1    478    hom    8.64
 AC0    1    583    het    37.77
 AC0    1    588    het    37.77
 AC0    1    619    hom    92.03

 file2.txt
 Sam    string    POS    zyg    QUAL
 AC1    1    619    hom    89.03
 AC1    1    746    hom    17.86
 AC1    1    810    het    2680.77
 AC1    1    849    het    200.77

awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '!c {
        c=$0"\tcol6";
        next
    }
    NR==FNR {
        a[$2$3]=$0 "\t";
        next
    }
    {
        if ( ($5>=2) && (FNR > 1) ) {
          if ( $2$3 in a ) {
             a[$2$3]=a[$2$3] $1 ",";
          } else {
             print $0 > "Errors.txt";
          }
        }
    }
    END {
         print c;
         for (i in a) {
            print a[i]
        }
    }' input.txt file*
```

For the above input files it prints the below output:

```
AC0,AC1,
WSS    1    389    hom    62.74 
AC1,
WSS    1    810   hom    3548.77    AC1,
WSS    1    689   hom    4.12   
WSS    1    1250      hom    4973.77
```

It still prints the values in $1 from file1 and file2

Comment: How about if we add a tab in the first block and append a comma each time we add an ID? Would that work? The trailing commas can later be removed.

Comment: Yeah!! trailing comma is not an issue  which can be removed later. I would try this on real data and see if it helps in terms of processing time.Will keep posted

Comment: It doesn't look like doing any faster!! Do you have any idea on what Etan Resiner suggested?

Comment: "col1, col1" is coming from the header lines of file1.txt and file2.txt.  It can be prevented by adding the condition `&& FNR > 1` to `$5 >= 2`.  Even better is to remove the header lines and blank lines from these files to avoid spending time to make these checks.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue. There is chr1 in output, but I don't see it in input. There is some additional space in the beginning of files and that may causing some of these issues.

Comment: chr is removed from the input files while pasting  the input here to make it simple and failed to remove in output, otherwise it is same. I do not have any spaces in the input files. Here are the sample files with 5 lines each to see if you can reproduce the error. `http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g1896c42aebdd0906999743645c313e3afc18c7265` . this could help to see if there are other issues with OS..

Comment: Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Did these changes to awk script address the main issue? Did they improve performance? If not, an alternative should be explored. If yes, then it is worth spending time on fine tuning

Comment: yes, these changes made a slight improvement in performance and does what is required, except those additional rows with values in $1 are getting printed which is not required.

Comment: Everything works as expected. The only culprit is those extra rows.

Comment: This approach is based on the assumption that all the keys are present in input.txt   Now the code has been changed to work without this assumption. I would suggest to remove the header lines and blank lines before processing. It seems there is only slight improvement in performance and I would highly recommend trying the other ideas suggested here.

Comment: Still something wrong. Now it prints all the rows from all the files. It just needs to add the values in $1 from files file1..filen  to input.txt if the keys are present.  i.e. the output will have only the rows from input.txt with an extra column having $1 values from the rest of the files.

Comment: seems there is some misunderstanding about the required output. I have now shown how the required output should be. Hope this makes it clear to finetune.

Comment: In that case, input.txt must have all keys which are read and stored by the script in the first pass. Now, this code expects this and if a key is found in one of the files, but not in input.txt, it logs that case in Errors.txt